# How to change definition level on google maps ? (not zoom !)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm looking for a way to use a higher definition level on google maps: in particular for a printed version.

The idea here is to make everything smaller to allow a better "zoom" level on a map.

An example will be more efficient:
[image: An exemple with css zoom property, wich render 2 maps on same size on screen]

As you can see here, by using a zoom:0.6 and a bigger div, Google Maps allow a higher zoom so my map is more detailed, and staying the same size on screen:

```
#div1 { width:670px ; height:550px ; }
#div2 { zoom:0.6 ; width:1116px ; height:916px ; }
```

You have also a jsfiddle example here :
https://jsfiddle.net/1v8pgqb8/

It could work like this but I'm not sure if it can work on every browsers, and it looks a bit "bad" to me.

So my question here is: is there a way to change the "definition level" on Google maps, so you can have the same div width but everything is smaller, so you can use a better zoom level? Sort of a PPP of DPI...

Not sure if I'm really clear but I couldn't find anything on this problem...

Thanks for you help!

Comment: This [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/what-ratio-scales-do-google-maps-zoom-levels-correspond-to) could be interesting to get you started. Also note, print dimension is relative to the screen dimension!